# No Module Named 'Symbol'

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

I have problem with my pip . Lately I was getting error when I was trying to install any packages The Error was: ( Pyautogui )

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rati_\OneDrive\Desktop\PyAutoGUI-0.9.53.tar\PyAutoGUI-0.9.53\PyAutoGUI-0.9.53\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
  File "C:\Users\rati_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "C:\Users\rati_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\Users\rati_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\rati_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 29, in <module>
    import symbol
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'symbol'
```

I reinstalled pip , python but couldn't fix the error ...
There was no information online so I couldn't fix it.
Any Tips?

Comment: Have you tried ```import symbol``` instead of ```import Symbol```? We are talking about ```symbol-please```, right? If so, you can also try ```import symbol_please```.

Comment: Try to upgrade both pip and setuptools as well `python3 -m pip install pip setuptools --upgrade`

Comment: I Did and it worked Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Module [`symbol`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/symbol.html) was a part of the standard library since the dawn of time. It was declared deprecated in [Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/symbol.html) and finally removed in 3.10. For Python 3.10 one has to upgrade any 3rd-party library that imports `symbol`. In your case the libraries are `pip`/`setuptools`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

If upgrade is not possible or there is no newer version of libraries updated for Python 3.10 the only solution is to downgrade Python.

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought `pip install setuptools` would work, but it doesn't upgrade it.

Comment: How exactly is it possible to end up with an out-of-date pip and setuptools after updating to a newer Python version? They come with the Python installation! They aren't third-party at all, `pip` is supposed to provision its own compatible `setuptools`, and even if you go out of your way to suppress installing `pip`, it's supposed to be possible to bootstrap it from `ensurepip`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Have you seen the traceback in the question? Python 3.10, `import symbol`  in `pkg_resources`.

Comment: ...But I thought `pkg_resources` is itself only supposed to exist because `setuptools` put it there... ? It's not like a *Python installation* can be upgraded in-place, last I checked.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "*pkg_resources is itself only supposed to exist because setuptools put it there... ?*" Yes, that's why my answer says "pip install --upgrade … setuptools". "*It's not like a Python installation can be upgraded in-place, last I checked.*" But `pip`/`setuptools` can be downgraded later. That's perhaps what happened with the OP but you should ask their.

Comment: Ah, I guess it would have to have been something like that... perhaps indirectly by a *system* package manager having pinned a version inappropriately?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Could be simple `pip install -U setuptools==<some old version>`

Answer (score 1):

I just reinstalled pip3 with [the (official?) pip installer](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). Since then it worked again.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me. Even though an error messaeg showed up at the end. ```ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pip-accel 0.43 requires pip<7.2,>=7.0, but you have pip 22.3.1 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: The error message means that the wheel `pip-accel 0.43` is only compatible with pip version 7.0 and 7.1 and no other version. You could try reinstalling `pip-accel` to get a newer version compatible with `pip` version 22+. If it doesn't break anything you can safely ignore the error I think.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I had to reinstall the entire Python, if you are using a virtual environment, just extract and backup your requirements.txt file and get a new fresh virtual environment!
For libraries like pywin32 that are notorious for breaking the virtual environment, you should consider installing then manually (here I manually place their code from the GitHub repo into the `venv/.../libs/pythonx/site-packages/ directory` )